# Imagebox convert to bitmap

Tags: c#, winforms, emgucv

I am writing a C# program which use the webcam to capture image.
For the box to output image, `imagebox` (in `EmguCV` library) is chosen.
I am willing to get the pixel information from the output image.
According to my finding, I need to convert the image in `imagebox` to bitmap then I can use the `picturebox` in c# to perform the analysis
(http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images#Using_ImageBox)
So, Tobitmap() method is requied. Can anyone give me idea on how to convert the imagebox image to bitmap base on the function?
Many thanks

```
private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
{
   ImageFrame = _capture.QueryFrame();
   detectimageBox.Image = ImageFrame;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the Image into the Bitmap constructor:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(detectImageBox.Image);
```

You can, of course, create an extension:

```
    public static Bitmap ToBitmap(this PictureBox imageBox)
    {
        return new Bitmap(imageBox.Image)
    }
```

Call it like:

```
Bitmap bitmap = detectImageBox.ToBitmap();
```

NOTE: I've done no null checks or anything here, I'd advise you include them though.

Comment: This is not casting - a new bitmap instance is created.

Comment: Don't know why I've used that terminology. Tired I think. Edited post.